# Opening contents of a JList in new window

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I'm very new to Java.

I've created two `JLists` in which you can add and remove 'shopping cart' items.

Once the user has added all their items they can click a `submit` button to view their selected items in a new window.

My first list is `itemList` (populated with items from array), the second list is `shoppinglist` which gets populated with whatever the user selects with a `JButton`.

Additional arrays are created to handle the actions of the buttons moving the items to and from the `JLists`. I've tried a few things, but haven't been successful in showing the items that get selected and shown in `shopinglist` to appear in a new window once `submit` is hit.

Any help is much appreciated.

```
//Create itemList
itemList = new JList(shopping);
contentPane.add(itemList);
itemList.setVisibleRowCount(10);
    itemList.setFixedCellHeight(20);
    itemList.setFixedCellWidth(140);
    itemList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);


    //Add JScrollPane to maintain size
    JScrollPane list1 = new JScrollPane(itemList);
    //contentPane.add(list1);

    //Create shoppingList
    shoppingList = new JList(items);
    contentPane.add(shoppingList);
    shoppingList.setVisibleRowCount(10);
    shoppingList.setFixedCellHeight(20);
    shoppingList.setFixedCellWidth(140);
    shoppingList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);

    //Add JScrollPane to maintain size
    JScrollPane list2 = new JScrollPane(shoppingList);

    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();

    //contentPane.add(list2);

    Buttonin = new JButton(">>");
    //Buttonin.setBounds(144, 46, 60, 23);
    Buttonin.addActionListener(this);
    buttonPanel.add(Buttonin);

    ButtonOut = new JButton("<<");
    //ButtonOut.setBounds(144, 80, 60, 23);
    ButtonOut.addActionListener(this);
    buttonPanel.add(ButtonOut);

    JPanel submitPanel = new JPanel();

    submitButton = new JButton("Submit");
    submitPanel.add(submitButton);

    submitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent az) {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Go Shopping!");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.getContentPane().add(new MyPanel2());
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);

        }
    });


    contentPane.add(list1);
    contentPane.add(buttonPanel);
    contentPane.add(list2);
    contentPane.setOpaque(true);
    contentPane.add(submitPanel);
    return contentPane;


}




public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{
    int i = 0;

    //When in buttonin is pressed index and value of selected item is output to array

    if (e.getSource() == Buttonin)
    {

        int[] fromindex = itemList.getSelectedIndices();
        Object[] from = itemList.getSelectedValues();

        //add items to the shoppingList
        for (i = 0; i < from.length; i++)
        {
            items.addElement(from[i]);

        }
        //Must remove items that are selected from the itemList
        for (i = (fromindex.length-1); i >= 0; i--)
        {
            shopping.remove(fromindex[i]);
        }

    }   


    //When out button is pressed index and value of selected item is output to new array

    else if (e.getSource() == ButtonOut)
    {
        Object[] to = shoppingList.getSelectedValues();
        int [] toindex = shoppingList.getSelectedIndices();

        //add items to previous list
           for(i = 0; i < to.length; i++)
            {
                shopping.addElement(to[i]);
            }
         //Must remove what's deselected
           for (i = (toindex.length-1); i >= 0; i--)
            {
                items.remove(toindex[i]);
            }
    }
```

Ok, bear with me (very very new to java) is this how I would set up the constructor to reference to ProfileFrame objects? And if so how do I change my main to reflect the new constructor?

```
public class GoShopping extends JPanel {

private JList shopList;

public GoShopping(ProfileFrame slist) {
//construct components


shopList = new JList(slist.getListModel());
shopList.setBounds(6, 6, 123, 166);//don't worry I'm changing the layout
add(shopList);
}


public static void main (String[] args) {
JFrame frame = new JFrame ("MyPanel");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

//I need new GoShopping to reflect the new constructor, but not sure how to make it    work
frame.getContentPane().add (new GoShopping());
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible (true);
}
}
```

Comment: If you want to display the same list in a new window, simply get the ListModel from the original JList and stuff it into the new one. Easy as `Math.PI`.

Comment: Ok I tried doing as you suggested by first adding a getter for the ListModel to the ProfileFrame class:  public ListModel getListModel(){ return shopping; } and trying to retreive it in a second class MyPanel2 and I'm getting a 'dataModel must be non null' error. I'm still not sure what I'm doing wrong :/                  public MyPanel2() {
    //construct components
 
 ProfileFrame pframe = new ProfileFrame();    
    shopList = new JList(pframe.getListModel());
    shopList.setBounds(6, 6, 123, 166);
    add(shopList);
}

Comment: You're using a null model -- don't do that. If you need to show us code, please don't do it in a comment since that is obviously non-readable. Edit your original post and add the latest code to the bottom. Also, don't setBounds or use null layout. Use the layout managers unless you like making things more difficult than they need to be. See answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a new ProfileFrame object in your MyPanel2 constructor, and since this is not the same instance as the visualized ProfileFrame object, then its JList's model will be null. A bad solution is to use static variables -- just don't do this please. A better solution is to pass a reference to the true visualized ProfileFrame object into your MyPanel2 constructor and call the public methods off of this instance.

And again, don't use null layout and `setBounds(...)`, but instead use the layout managers unless you like making things more difficult than they need to be.